Why does the project stop working when I cp -r nodeProject/* newLoc?
80% of the time I copy a Node.js (or Angular) project, I have to rm -rf node_modules and npm install again. I am wondering why, as cp -r dir/* dir is extremely stable and I did this in Java all the time.
I get an error like this on my Node.js project:
dean@Deans-MacBook-Pro server % ./node_modules/.bin/concurrently
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1222
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '../src/defaults'
Require stack:
- /Users/dean/workspace/biltup/biltup/server/node_modules/.bin/concurrently
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1219:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1045:27)
    at TracingChannel.traceSync (node:diagnostics_channel:315:14)
    at wrapModuleLoad (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:215:24)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1304:12)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:123:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/dean/workspace/biltup/biltup/server/node_modules/.bin/concurrently:32:31)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1504:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1588:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1282:32) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/dean/workspace/biltup/biltup/server/node_modules/.bin/concurrently'
  ]
}

Node.js v22.5.0

I get an error like this on my Angular project
dean@Deans-MacBook-Pro client % npm run dev

> fuse-angular@20.0.0 dev
> ng serve

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1222
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './bootstrap'
Require stack:
- /Users/dean/workspace/biltup/biltup/client/node_modules/.bin/ng
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1219:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1045:27)
    at TracingChannel.traceSync (node:diagnostics_channel:315:14)
    at wrapModuleLoad (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:215:24)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1304:12)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:123:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/dean/workspace/biltup/biltup/client/node_modules/.bin/ng:70:3)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1467:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1551:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1282:32) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/Users/dean/workspace/biltup/biltup/client/node_modules/.bin/ng' ]
}

Node.js v22.4.0


please share the minimal reproducible code, if possible a stackbitz or github repo with the issue replicated

The short answer is that Some packages or their dependencies may use symlinks. We usually don't carry the node_moudles folder in the project.
